# Error! Get request in Vuejs with axios (401 Unauthorized)

Tags: vue.js, axios

when I call the method "getStates" I unfortunately get a 401 (Unauthorized)" [image: error]. But if call with GET and the same headers in Postman, it works! How i set my GET request headers??

getStates method:

```
getStates() {
  this.axios
    .get(
      this.baseURL + "states",
      {
        params: {
          id: this.city,
        },
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.token
        },
      })
    .then((response) => {
      this.states = response.data.data;
      console.warn(response.data.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {});
  this.apiLoaded = true;
}
```

Comment: you probably want withCredentials = true on your axios instance

Comment: I tried, but this not works

Comment: Are you sure token is valid, can you check the network tab in de devtools? Make sure the call and all its headers is right like in postman.

Comment: Yes, token is valid and all its headers is same as postman

Comment: Does your server allow [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) requests?

Comment: Yes, All Get API is worked properly, only params req GET request shows Unauthorized

Comment: what is the axios version ? @GeetaNinawe

Comment: @Mahdad axios version : ^0.21.4

Comment: the last version is 0.22.0 @GeetaNinawe

Answer (score 0):

try this

./App.vue :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="getStatesInfo">Click</button>
    <p>{{ states }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { getStates } from "./services";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      states: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getStatesInfo() {
      getStates()
        .then((res) => {
          this.states = res;
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

./services/index.js :

```
const baseUrl = "http://localhost:4000/";
const axios = require("axios");
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseUrl,
  timeout: 60000,
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + "your-token",
  },
});

export async function getStates() {
  const response = await instance.get("/states", {
    params: {
      id: "param1",
    },
  });

  return response.data;
}
```